# How to call git commands on private repo using cygwin to execute bash script in Jenkins

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, cygwin

I am having trouble connecting to a remote repo through execute shell in Jenkins. I am on a Windows server and am using cygwin in order to run bash commands. I am getting the error that I do not have host-authentication rights to connect to the repo. However, I am able to connect via the Git-Plugin. Any suggestions? Thanks!

[Snapshot of execute shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7rZd.png)
[Snapshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSuGt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be related to this [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26680) and Jenkins does not like the slash in your path.

You can probably specify the absolute path to the repo with trailing slash, and see if it helps

```
ip-address:/absolute/path/to/repo/external-web/repo.git
```

Comment: This worked! However, now I am getting a host verification error. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: [Delete Branches] $ c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login C:\Users\tbraga\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson7663783267572060311.sh
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: The acces is via ssh, so machine with git shoud know about public key of the user, Jenkins uses to ssh. Or you specify your user in ssh credentials?

Comment: Shouldn't it already know if the connection works via the git-plugin?

Comment: even if you specify absolute path?

Comment: yes... do you know if there is a way to see where jenkins is pulling the key from?